# Как выгрузить программу из памяти при закрытии окна?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Как выгрузить программу из памяти при закрытии окна? При нажатии на кнопку закрытия окна программа остается висеть в памяти.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы приложение полностью закрылось после закрытия окна,

- на окна должно указывать свойство `Application.MainWindow`,
- свойство `Application.ShutdownMode` должно быть равным `OnMainWindowClose`.

Кроме того, можно явно закрыть приложение в требуемом месте

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

Если точнее, то не

```
Application.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
```

а

```
Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
```